# How Would I Show pwndbg or GEF Menus After Stepping at Breakpoint, But Without Stepping Again?

Tags: c, debugging, assembly, gdb, disassembly

How would I show the default menus for pwndbg (https://github.com/pwndbg/pwndbg) (e.g. disassemble, code, stack trace, ..etc) that are shown by default when a step is made, and the program is paused at a certain breakpoint, but without having to make another step to show those menus? I would like to ask the same question as well for GEF (https://github.com/hugsy/gef)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the answer I was looking for. It is the command "context" that produces the menus once again!!

Comment: By the way, ctx is an alias of context.